# Api Authentication Methods

Tags: api, security, authentication, https, api-key

I've created a small wishlist project.

I wan't to serve an API for users, which have an API Key.

My webserver run on TLS (HTTPS). It is safe for users to send api key in clear in the http headers like that ?

`curl -H "Authorization: api_key MY_APP_API_KEY" https://myapp.example.com`

Otherwise, what should I use ?

I would like not to use OAuth2, which is too complex for my little project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe.. HTTPS encrypts all message contents, including the HTTP headers and the request/response data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Web product?

If so, keep in mind your MY_APP_API_KEY will be fully available in the browser.

If it is a Web product, maybe consider a simple alternative like https://pay2my.app for logins (I'm involved in that OSS project)?  Users login browser-side and send their own token + signature to the server:  server just validates that.

Otherwise you're already good to go as per the first answer .

Comment: it is an evaluation project as part of my studies. we make a wish list so no sensitive data but we are still evaluated on the security of our application (web server)